# LINQ to return empty result

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I want to write a LINQ to return empty list always. I can do that in SQL as

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE 1=2
```

How to do it in LINQ?

My exact scenario is

```
private IQueryable <EMPLOYEE> getEmployee()
{
   IQueryable <EMPLOYEE> employees;

   //code

   if(condition)
   {
     return employees
   }
   else
   {
     //here I want to return a empty result.
   }
}
```

Comment: `Enumerable.Empty<T>()`, or `someEnumerable.Where(t => false)`? What do you mean by "a LINQ query" anyway? What have you tried and why doesn't that work? Read [ask], please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to hit database. You can use following:

```
private IQueryable <EMPLOYEE> getEmployee()
{
    return Enumerable.Empty<EMPLOYEE>().AsQueryable();
}
```

Comment: This will always return an empty list, in his code example it seems like he also wants to return in some cases some results based on a particular condition.

Comment: @svenQ That's no biggie; he can just put this code in an if statement if that's the case